# Rails Model Validation to check the value of an attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a `Project` model and a `User` model. A project must have a client (User class) and so the `Project` model has a `client_id` foreign key.

The `User` model has a `type` attribute and will contain `3` if the user is a client.

I want to validate that when a project is assigned to a client, that `@user.type` is `3`.

Project.rb

```
validates :client_id, presence: true, #@user.type must be 3
belongs_to :client, :class_name => User, :foreign_key => :client_id
```

User.rb

```
#constants
TYPES = {
    :manager => 1,
    :contractor => 2,
    :client => 3
}
```

Not to sure how to go about the validation. I read through the rails guide on validations but still can't seem to get a solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Use the `inclusion` validation helper. [Docs here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#inclusion)

Here's a quick example from the docs

```
class Coffee < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :size, :inclusion => { :in => %w(small medium large),
    :message => "%{value} is not a valid size" }
end
```

---

EDIT:

Ok, I see what you mean. Don't use validation helpers for this, do it manually.

```
# somewhere in your model (don't be tempted to put this in your controller)
def assigning_client
  if @user.type == 3
    # do the assignment
  else
    errors.add(:base, :message => "User must be a client")
  end
end
```

The error will prevent the info from being saved as long as you use the bang version `save!` which forces validation.

Comment: Is it possible to use the `inclusion` helper to say "only those users ids who's `type` is `3`? I've been trying, but can't get it to work.

Comment: `validates :user_type, :inclusion => { :in => [3] }`

Comment: no no, sorry maybe I wasn't clear. This is saving a user ID. BUT The user who's ID is being saved, must have `3` as their `type` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Just a pointer here. Don't use an attribute named type in your activerecord models. It conflicts with the way rails uses STI(Single Table Inheritance) as it uses the type attribute to determine the type of the class when its subclassing another